# jQuery find only the next form element on click in the DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I am having a hard time with this. Basically there is a list of microblog posts. Directly after each post there is an edit form for it, but initially set to display none in css. I only want to show (slideToggle) the edit form which is directly after the microblogpost in which the edit link ($this) was clicked.

Note: In the description below I mention only. What I mean is that there are many edit forms on the page, but I only want to show the one after the article.post in which the a.edit_this was clicked.

```
<div id="microblog">
    <article class="post">
      <figure class="av">
    <img src="avatarurl" alt="">
      </figure>
      <div class="post_text">
    <h3>Post title <span> <a href="#" class="edit_this">Edit link</a></span>   <span>Delete</span></h3>
    <div class="postmeta">Date<span>Time</span></div>
           <p>Post body</p>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="details">Details</a>
      </div>
    </article>  <-- End of micropost

    <form class="edit_form">  <-- Need to show only this when clicking on the .edit_this 
                                  link in the above micropost
    </form>

    <article class="post"> <-- Beginning of next micropost
      <figure class="av">
    <img src="avatarurl" alt="">
      </figure>
      <div class="post_text">
    <h3>Post title <span> <a href="#" class="edit_this">Edit link</a></span>   <span>Delete</span></h3>
    <div class="postmeta">Date<span>Time</span></div>
           <p>Post body</p>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="details">Details</a>
      </div>
    **</article>**  <-- End of micropost
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.edit_this').on('click',function(){    
    $(this).closest('.post').next('.edit_form').slideToggle();
});
```

You could have to use nextAll() if more than one article for each form edit

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't seem to work. If I add preventDefault() to it, then it prevents the default behaviour, but slideToggle doesn't work.

Comment: Is the .edit_form always just after the corresponding article?

Comment: "Is the .edit_form always just after the corresponding article?" - Yes. Strange. Doesn't seem to work for me. Will double check it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure where the micropost is above, but:

If it's actually *after* (not within) the micropost, then if the form is the *very* next element:

```
$this.next().slideToggle();
```

If it follows the micropost but with some elements in-between:

```
$this.nextAll("selector for edit form").first().slideToggle();
```

If it's *within* the micropost, then:

```
$this.find("selector for edit form").slideToggle();
```